# how to get kendo ui mobile style silver

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, kendo-dataviz

OK - I clearly don't get this - my css links include:

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />
    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="kendo/styles/kendo.dataviz.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

All files exist, and my `app.js` skin is set to `'silver'`

problem is, that I get a buggy display, as if it's not loading the silver display...

I have charts, so I need dataviz, 
I have a slider, so I need the kendo.common.min.css (,aybe I need a silver.css file for this too, I don't know)

and if I change to "flat" the flat theme is displayed perfectly with everything in its right place, but for some reason silver won't render correctly, can anybody tell me what I'm misunderstanding about the includes?

Kind Regards

**EDIT**
Now I am in a place where I have the following stylesheet references:

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.dataviz.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Now I can either include the last stylesheet:

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.silver.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

if I do that, buttons display correctly, but the slider does not, but if I include

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

then the slider works, but buttons and switches and the normal mobile controls do not display correctly. How can I correct this, so I have both a silver styled slider and buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kendo UI mobile themes are self contained and furthermore the mobile themes and the web mobile skins cannot work together. Thus, you should remove kendo.mobile.all.min.css from your app.

Additionally the web mobile skins don't need an app setting, as they work as the web ones do, so you don't need to set skin: "silver". You may need to load the web Silver skin though.

Check [Kendo UI documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/regular-usage) for more info and an example.

Also, keep in mind that the web mobile skins are not intended to be used for whole mobile app styling.

Comment: can you elaborate on the last comment that web mobile slkins are not intended to be used for whole mobile app styling?

Comment: I meant that they were created to be used in Kendo UI desktop pages and not in a mobile app. They will work in an app, but we didn't extensively test them in apps, so there might be styling bugs.